# Reference request: Tate's conjecture for L functions of motives

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, motives

What's a good reference for the most general form of Tate's conjecture for the order of poles of the L function of a motive? Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at Schneider's survey article in the book on the Beilinson conjectures edited by Rapoport, Schappacher and Schneider.

Comment: Thank you, @DamianRössler. Scheider's paper is from 30 years ago. I was wondering if there are any more recent articles (post Voevodsky's works).